# Call api with PowerShell having & in the endpoint is throwing error in sql job

Tags: api, powershell, sql-job

My PowerShell script: in file.ps1

```
param([string]$url)

$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.Method ="GET"
$req.ContentLength = 0

$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($resp.GetResponseStream())
$reader.ReadToEnd()
```

My sql job step looks like this

```
powershell.exe C:\JobScripts\file.ps1 http://localhost:4100/api/Reports?parm1=val1&param2=val2
```

When I run the job I get Ampersand error. I am not sure how to add parameters in this case without using `&`. I am new to PowerShell.

Comment: Does this work: `powershell.exe -File C:\JobScripts\file.ps1 'http://localhost:4100/api/Reports?parm1=val1&param2=val2'`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But no. I got the answer . I had to make it like this http://localhost:4100/api/Reports?parm1=val1%26param2=val2

Comment: Odd - the version I typed works fine for me.  You might want to add your solution as an actual answer so people are more likely to see it.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper: Then, if you have the answer please post it that we can see your question is answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - powershell.exe -File C:\JobScripts\file.ps1  http://localhost:4100/api/Reports?parm1=val1%26param2=val2